# JSON Parse Error while inserting data in to MySQL database in React Native

Tags: php, react-native

I am trying to insert data into `MySQL` database on a server in `React Native`.

**Problem**

Data is inserted successfully in the database but i am getting an error message saying

> JSON Parse error: Unexpected Identifier "Database"

I can't seem to find where the issue exists. My guess is that issue is somewhere in the response message that i get from server.

**Question**

What am i doing wrong here and please help me fix this error.

Here's the function to send data to server

```
registerUser = () => {
    fetch('http://netnock.com/yousaf/RNMYSQL/register_user.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        username: this.state.username,
        userPassword: this.state.userPassword
      })
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((parsedJson) => {
      Alert.alert('Success',
                  parsedJson.responseMsg,
                 [{text: 'OK'}]);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Alert.alert('Error',
                  error.message,
                  [{text: 'OK'}]);
    });
}
```

and here's the PHP script to insert data in to database

```
<?php

    require 'DbConnection.php';

    $dbCon = getDbConnection();

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    $userEmail = $obj['email'];
    $username = $obj['username'];
    $userPassword = $obj['userPassword'];

    $sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO Users (Email, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    $statement = $dbCon->prepare($sqlQuery);

    if($statement) {
        $statement->bind_param('sss', $userEmail, $username, $userPassword);

        if($statement->execute()) {
            $responseMsg = [
                responseMsg => 'User Registered Successfully'
            ];

            $jsonResponse = json_encode($responseMsg);
            echo $jsonResponse;
        }
    }

    $statement->close();
    $dbCon->close();

?>
```

Comment: Getting an error in PHP?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: `responseMsg => 'User Registered Successfully'` should be `'responseMsg' => 'User Registered Successfully'`. You need to quote array keys or PHP will throw a warning/notice.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers development tools and see what the page actually returns.

Comment: In your `DbConnection.php`, you have an echo saying `Database Connected`. Remove all output before you echo the json, or the result won't be valid json and the javascript won't be able to parse it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You sir are a life saver. Quotes around `responseMsg` fixed the issue. Thank you very much and yes i know that passwords should not be stored in clear text. I am just a beginner in react native, so was practicing somethings that i learned recently

Comment: A suggestion, never knowingly write insecure code. Not even for testing. Before you know it, you will continue with your test script or copy it for something and forget about the security issues. It's also a waste of time debugging code that should be rewritten anyway.